# SchemaExport create/drop, nvarchar always have length 1

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to create/delete schema in tests:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
   var config = new Configuration();

  config.Configure(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"));
  (new[] { typeof(Entity).Assembly }).ToList().ForEach(a => config.AddAssembly(a));

  var export = new SchemaExport(config);

   export.Create(false, true);
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
   var config = new Configuration();

  config.Configure(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"));
  (new[] { typeof(Entity).Assembly }).ToList().ForEach(a => config.AddAssembly(a));

  var export = new SchemaExport(config);

   export.Drop(false, true);
}
```

When tables are generated, all `nvarchar` columns have length 1. Can you explain to me why?

This is example of mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="TSS.Domain" namespace="TSS.Domain" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Status" table="DicStatus" schema="dbo" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" type="Guid">
      <column name="id" not-null="true" sql-type="uniqueidentifier" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="String">
      <column name="name" not-null="true" length="256" sql-type="nvarchar" />
    </property>
    <property name="CreatedAt" type="DateTime">
      <column name="createdAt" not-null="true" sql-type="datetime" />
    </property>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">***;</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="max_fetch_depth">1</property>
    <property name="command_timeout">60</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 1, no 0</property>
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post also your session factory configuration? Which sql dialect are you using?

Comment: @nemesv: updated topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lenght is only used if you are using the default column type so when you don't have the `sql-type` specified. So if you write

```
<property name="Name" type="String">
   <column name="name" not-null="true" length="256" />
</property>
```

It will generate the `name` column with `nvarchar(256)` because `nvarchar` is default column type for string in the MsSql2008Dialect.

Or you can specify explicitly the  `sql-type` but in your case you cannot use length but you need write out the full type `nvarchar(256)`:

```
<property name="Name" type="String">
   <column name="name" not-null="true" sql-type="nvarchar(256)" />
</property>
```